# SQL command can not get word related sentence

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a sentence from database which is related to give word.
suppose here is a mysql table.

```
id-      sentence  
1-     This is a web page  
2-     This is spiderweb   
3-     Here is a webspider     
4-     create anyWebPage
```

Here is a simple code.

```
<?php  
     // ignore all syntax error in this code if present.
     $input = 'web';
     $sql = mysql_query("
            SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
            WHERE sentence LIKE('%$input%')
     ");
 // echo The given result.
 ?>
```

If I use `LIKE %....%` Then all result are displayed.
If I use `LIKE ...%` Then it can not give any result because there is no sentence which is start from `$input = 'web';`
I want to get those sentence in which world is start from **web**
Required Result
1- This is a **web** Page
3 - Here is a **webspider**

Please guide me how can I get Like these result.
Thanks........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quotes should be around `%`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) not inside them, like `LIKE('%$input%')`. Note that whatever string comparison you use it's dependant on whether [collation is case sensitive or insensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html):

> The default character set and collation are latin1 and
>   latin1_swedish_ci, so nonbinary string comparisons are case
>   insensitive by default. This means that if you search with col_name
>   LIKE 'a%', you get all column values that start with A or a.

[`mysql_`](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) is deprecated, use [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO::`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

You're not escaping input ([SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)).

<del>You're declaring `$inpput` and using `$input`.</del>

Also check [`FULLTEXT` search options in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) for speed optimization.

Or if you need to match whole words **only** you may use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE sentence REGEXP '([^[:alnum:]]|^)$input([^[:alnum:]]|$)'
```

[Example here](http://pastebin.com/PANtzKtv)<sub>1</sub> where `[^[:alnum:]]` matches everything except number and letters (coma, full stop, dash) and `^/$` beginning/end of the string respectively.

<sub>[**1**] just pastebin, [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) is down right now :-/</sub>

Comment: It gets only one result that  
`1- This is a web page` But `3- Here is a webspider` also a required result.

Comment: ok, use this command this give a require result  
`SELECT * FROM test WHERE sentence REGEXP '([^[:alnum:]]|^)$input'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
                    WHERE sentence LIKE('% ". $input. "%')");
```

You should add space character.

Comment: I wondered about downvoting me, may be someone does not noticed the space character I have added. :)

Comment: [`LIKE` need quotes in its syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the space character needs to be part of your WHERE LIKE criteria. You could put it between the % and web.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are wanting to do a Full Text Search - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html
It is done using the syntax - [`MATCH() ... AGAINST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match)

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE MATCH(sentence) AGAINST('$input*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

note `*` is the wildcard search in Full Text Searches. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: It can only get `3- Here is a webspider` but `1- This is a web page` is also a required result.

Answer (score 0):

Nabheet's answer is correct, but it misses the case where the first word of the string begins with the search term (e.g, "web").  This query addresses both of these cases:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE sentence LIKE "$input%" or sentence LIKE "% $input%" ;");
```

The first clause in this query will detect when the first word in the sentence begins with the search term, and the second clause will detect when any other words begin with the search term.

The other answers are right to point out the importance of sanitizing your search term to prevent against SQL injection.